The display link you entered is invalid - Facebook Ad Manager
I was trying to set up ads for my website on facebook, and the url is working even when I click preview it takes me to the site and it loads, but it says the url is invalid. This is the error message:
The display link that you entered is invalid. Please check your display link and try again. (#2016017)
This is the url:
https://essentials-emporium-online.myshopify.com/products/pressure-point-therapy-neck-massager
